# Password and password hash in a model and in db table

Tags: scala, postgresql-9.2, playframework-2.2, anorm

I have a table `User(id, password_hash, ....)` in db and a model for it:

```
case class User(
  id: Pk[Long] = NotAssigned,
  email: String,
  password: Option[String] = None,
  passwordHash: Option[String] = None
)


object User {

  def create(newUser: User): Option[Long] = //.....

  //on("password_hash" -> generatePasswordHash(newUser.password)

  def generatePasswordHash(p: String) = //....
 }
```

The point is `Password` field exists only the model `User` and is filled up only I register a new user:

```
val newUser = User(email = emailFromForm, password = Some(passwordFromForm))
```

I send to db only a hash of the password. Obviously, when I retrieve it from db, `Password` field in None but `PasswordHash` has a value.

I made `Password` and `PasswordHash` to be Option because I think they should be `Options`, shouldn't they? I'm not sure, though, whether it's right or wrong.

The question is my is this a good approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to have `User.password` at all?

```
case class User(
  id: Pk[Long] = NotAssigned,
  email: String,
  passwordHash: String 
)

object User {
  // or maybe Option[User] or Try[User]
  def create(email: String, password: String): Option[Long] = {
    val passwordHash = hashPassword(hash)
    val newUser = User(email, passwordHash)
    // save newUser to DB
  }

  // you may want to distinguish between "no such email" and "wrong password"
  // in which case you'd have something like Either[PasswordCheckFailure, User]
  def checkPassword(email: String, password: String): Option[User] = {
    val possibleUser: Option[User] = // get user by email
    possibleUser.filter(_.passwordHash = hashPassword(password))
  }

  private def hashPassword(password: String): String = ...
}
```

You may want to have a salt as well, see e.g. https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm. In this case you either store it in the same field as password or add another field:

```
case class User(
  id: Pk[Long] = NotAssigned,
  email: String,
  passwordHash: String,
  passwordSalt: String = // generate random string
)
```

Comment: perhaps, I don't need password because I need it only for creating a new user. In checkPassword, do you mean passwordHash?

Comment: I think I'll remove password field and remain passwordHash only. And I'll change a signature of create to be like yours.

Comment: "In checkPassword, do you mean passwordHash?" No, I do mean password you get from the login form, see the edit.

Comment: I see. I need to calculate a password hash inside "checkPassword", of course.